# How do I merge two arrays of Objects with a shared ID in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, merge

I have two Arrays of Objects, that share an ID.  How do I merge them into a single Array, where all items have been merged based on the ID?

I'm using TypeScript and Angular.

```
const array0 = [
  {
    subject_id: "711",
    topics: [ "Test", "Test2" ]
  },
  {
    subject_id: "712",
   topics: [ "topic1", "Topic2" ]
  }
];

const array1 = [
  {
    subject_id: 711,
    subject_name: "Science"
  },
  {
    subject_id: 712,
    subject_name: "Maths"
  }
];

I want the merged result to be:

const result = [
  {
    subject_id: "711",
    subjectName: "Science",
    topics: [ "Test", "Test2" ]
  },
  {
    subject_id: "712",
    subjectName: "Maths",
    topics: [ "topic1", "Topic2" ]
  }
];
```

Comment: How does subject_id: "711" match subject_id: 631, ???

Comment: @epascarello it was typing error sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use something like this:

```js
selectedSubjects = [
                     { subject_id: 711, topics: ["Test", "Test2"] },
                     { subject_id: 712, topics: ["topic1", "Topic2"] }
                   ]

theOtherSubjects = [
                     {subject_id: 711, subject_name: "Science"},
                     {subject_id: 712, subject_name: "Maths"}
                   ] // fixed the ids as I supposed the should be the same, otherwise it makes no sense with the provided data

let mergedSubjects = selectedSubjects.map(subject => {
    let otherSubject = theOtherSubjecs.find(element => element.subject_id === subject.subject_id)
    return { ...subject, ...otherSubject }
})
```

Comment: Nice. Can you please tell me how spread operator is working here? `return { ...subject, ...otherSubject } `

Comment: You can think of it this way: `{}` is a **new** object, and `...subject` spreads each key and its value. With that syntax, you spread those key/value pairs into the object defined by `{`and `}`. The "empty" object is the recipient of the `...` operation.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
selectedSubjects = [
    { subject_id: "711", topics: ["Test", "Test2"] },
    { subject_id: "712", topics: ["topic1", "Topic2"] }
  ];
  anotherArray = [
    { subject_id: 711, subject_name: "Science" },
    { subject_id: 712, subject_name: "Maths" }
  ];

  finalArray = [];

  createFinalArray() {
    this.selectedSubjects.map(s1 => {
      this.finalArray.push({
        subject_id: s1.subject_id,
        subject_name: this.anotherArray.find(s2 => s2.subject_id.toString()===s1.subject_id).subject_id,
        topics: s1.topics
      });
    })
  }
```